# Going through each ls line

Tags: linux, shell

I am new to shell scripting in linux. I want to be able to list the number of files in my directory, the number of directories in the directory and so fourth. I have decided to go upon this task by using

```
   ls -l | cut -c1-1
```

So this way I can get the first character of every ls command and then based on what it is, keep a count of file type until all files are listed. So an example would be if I was in a folder with a bunch of files and did the cut command from above, it would display many "-" permissions indicating it was a file.

My question is this, based on the command above, how would I go through each ls line? If I enter the command from above in the shell, it simply displays all of them at once... I would like to go through each ls line.

Thanks!

Directory is called Test and contains

```
 -rw-r--r--  1 teddy  user  31 27 Mar 10:07 test1.txt
 drwx------  1 teddy  user   9 30 Jan 19:18 tooney
 -rw-r--r--  1 teddy  user  31 27 Mar 10:07 test2.txt
 drwx------  1 teddy  user   9  21 Mar 11:32 dirt
```

Comment: why not just pipe it into more?  *| more*

Comment: @MichaelGardner Have not considered it but if it works then why not indeed :). Can you provide an example? Thank you

Comment: Could you give us an example or two of what the output should look like or what you want to happen depending on what's in the directory being listed?

Comment: Okay, it contains those 4 entries and ... then what?  Are you asking how to iterate over them, e.g., using `foreach` in `tcsh` or `for` in `bash`?  I'm not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your method, you can calculate the totals using `uniq`, for example:

```
$ ls -l | cut -c1-1 | sort | uniq -c
    214 -
     13 d
      2 l
      1 t
```

`uniq -c` counts the number of consecutive occurrences of a line, and `sort` just puts them into some sorted order so that the same types end up together.

If you want these results in variables, then something this would be easier:

```
dirs=0
files=0

for name in *
do
    if [[ -d "$name" ]]
    then
        ((dirs++))
    elif [[ -f "$name" ]]
    then
        ((files++))
    # Possibly other things you want to count ...
    fi
done

echo "Files: $files"
echo "Directories: $dirs"
```

Comment: Ah perfect. How would I be able to modify this for example "There are 214 - types"

Comment: Can I put each line result in a variable? Thanks will accept either way

Comment: Putting them into variables is possible, but trickier. If you want the result you're better off uinsg a for loop, I'll update my answer.

Comment: It does not have to be a variable, I was just suggesting a way but clearly it is not the easiest:) Loop example would be perfect, thanks!

Comment: Sorry this may be very obvious but what is name equal to?

Comment: In the `for` loop, the glob (`*`) expands to every file/dir/etc in the current dir. `name` will have the name of one such file/dir each time the loop runs. You can see it by sticking an `echo $name` inside the loop.

Answer (score 4):

How about using `find` and `wc`:

```
# Find all files in the current directory 
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l

# Find all directories in the current directory 
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l
```

The command `wc` *(word count)* can be used to count the number of character, words and lines. Here `wc -l` counts the number of lines output from the results of `find`.

Answer (score 0):

Piping the command into more will keep it from scrolling off the screen.

```
ls -l | cut -c1-1 | more
```